Property 'value'' of object 'Backend' error when using QWebChannel in Python
Main module:
import f_main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    f_main.WMain.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

f_main module
class Backend(QtCore.QObject):
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._value = ""

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(str)
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, v):
        self._value = v
        self.valueChanged.emit(v)

class WB(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WB, self).__init__()
        self.settings = QSettings("MyCompany", "MyApp")
        geom = self.settings.value("geometry", "")
        s_ini._m['js'] = self.settings.value("js", {})
        if not s_ini._m['js']:
            s_ini._m['js'] = {}
        if geom != '':
            self.restoreGeometry(geom)
        
        self.backend = Backend()
        self.backend.valueChanged.connect(self.fromJS)
        self.webchannel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel()
        self.webchannel.registerObject("backend", self.backend)
        self.setPage(WebEnginePage(self))
        self.page().setWebChannel(self.webchannel)

Javascript in web page:
new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
    backend = channel.objects.backend;
});

But when I run get error:
Property 'value'' of object 'Backend' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
